# APP_INITIALIZER not work in angular6 library

Tags: angular, angular6

I create an angular6 library call mapModule, and be imported into app module, now I want to do something before load mapModule, so I try to add **APP_INITIALIZER** in this library :

```
export function StartupServiceFactory2(mapConfigService: MapConfigService) {
    const x = 2 + 2; 
    console.log(x);
    return () => mapConfigService.readConfig();
}
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Do you provide it?

```
// app.module
providers: [
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: StartupServiceFactory2,
   deps: [MapConfigService], multi: true }
]
```

Does `mapConfigService.readConfig()` return `Promise`?

Take a look at [example](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/)

Answer (score 1):

I have run into it as well, where`APP_INITIALIZER` wouldn't completely initialize the app before triggering `CanActivate` route guard.

Few things to look out for:

1. `mapConfigService` should return `Promise`
2. When converting `Observable` to promise via `toPromise()` and subsequently calling `.then()` - the promise is released before tapping into `.then()`:

This will have issue:

```
let promise = this.mapConfigService.map(...).toPromise().then(()=>{
 ///  this part of the code will NOT block the APP_INITIALIZER
 ///  meaning when toPromise() is called the promise is released 
 ///  right away before having a chance to fully execute the .then() part
       ....
});
```

Instead wrap the `Observable` into `Promise` and have the `resolve()` release the promise, like following:

```
readConfig(): Promise<any> {                                    
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                                    
            this.mapConfigService.subscribe((data)=> {
                // additional stuff

                resolve();
                return data;                
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Hope that helps.